# SQL QUERY multiple search in one row to find data from another row in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help with some code

I have a database table called "stuff" and I have this info:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| id   | member_id   |     group_id        |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1    |      11     |         aa          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2    |      22     |         aa          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 3    |      33     |         aa          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 4    |      44     |         bb          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 5    |      55     |         bb          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 6    |      66     |         bb          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I need to find the group id if I search all 3 members from one group

Something like:

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM stuff 
WHERE member_id=11 and member_id=22 and member_id=33
```

I know the query it is not valit but I don`t know how to make it valid.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  group_id
FROM    stuff
WHERE   member_id IN (11,22,33)
GROUP   BY group_id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00dadd/1)

if `member_id` is not unique for every `group_id`, you need to have `DISTINCT` in order to count only unique values.

```
SELECT  group_id
FROM    stuff
WHERE   member_id IN (11,22,33)
GROUP   BY group_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) = 3
```

More variations on this link:

- [SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)