# SQL Get unique value of group id where member id is one or more

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with some code

I have a database table called "stuff" and I have this info:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| id   | member_id   |     group_id        |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1    |      11     |         aa          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2    |      11     |         bb          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 3    |      22     |         bb          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 4    |      11     |         cc          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 5    |      22     |         cc          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 6    |      33     |         cc          |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

what I need:

```
If I search for group_id when member_id = 11 the result will be aa
If I search for group_id when member_id = 11 AND member_id = 22 the result will be bb
If I search for group_id when member_id = 11 AND member_id = 22 AND member_id = 33 the result will be cc
```

Comment: how is this different with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340885/sql-query-multiple-search-in-one-row-to-find-data-from-another-row-in-the-same-t

Comment: what if you search for meber_id: `22` and `33` what will be the corresponding `group_id`?

Comment: result will be nothing...null , I just need one result!

Comment: I need an update for this, I want to add: => LEFT/ JOIN other_table c on c.group_id=a/b.group_id WHERE other_id=42345345 . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  group_id
FROM    stuff
GROUP   BY group_id
HAVING  SUM(member_id = 11) = 1
        AND SUM(member_id = 22) = 1
        AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38629/3)

another variation,

```
SELECT  group_id
FROM    stuff a
WHERE   member_id IN (11,22,33)                 -- <<== list of member_id
        AND
        EXISTS
        (
          SELECT group_id
          FROM stuff b
          WHERE a.group_id = b.group_id
          GROUP BY group_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 3                   -- <<== number of member_id
        )
GROUP   BY group_id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3                            -- <<== number of member_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38629/6)

Comment: what about this? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372013/join-to-another-table-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN()` operator in your select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff
WHERE member_id IN(11,22,33);
```

In your front end, you can concatenate the values or your `member_id`'s separated by comma.

Comment: if I use SELECT * FROM stuff
WHERE member_id IN(11); the output will be aa bb cc, I just need aa

Comment: do you want `aa` because there are no other `member_id` on the group?

Answer (score 0):

Note that member_id cannot be at the same time both 11 and 22. Do you mean OR?
The following 2 queries will always return null:

```
search for group_id when member_id = 11 AND member_id = 22
search for group_id when member_id = 11 AND member_id = 22 AND member_id = 33
```

Comment: second variation of user 491243 worked

Comment: Yes, but "member_id IN (11,22,33)" means OR.