# Filter the output of a query with row from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with some code

I have 2 tables called "stuff" and "something" and I have this info:

```
               stuff                                  something
+-------------+---------------------+    +-------------+---------------------+
| member_id   |     group_id        |    |  group_id   |      some_id        |
+-------------+---------------------+    +-------------+---------------------+
|      11     |         aa          |    |      aa     |         7           |
|      11     |         bb          |    |      dd     |         8           |
|      22     |         bb          |    |      bb     |         9           |
|      11     |         cc          |    +-------------+---------------------+
|      22     |         cc          |
|      33     |         cc          |
|      11     |         dd          |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

This query:

```
SELECT  group_id
FROM    stuff a
WHERE   member_id IN (11)  -- <<== list of member_id (can be 11,22 or 22,33 or 11,22,33)
    AND
    EXISTS
    (
      SELECT group_id
      FROM stuff b
      WHERE a.group_id = b.group_id
      GROUP BY group_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1                   -- <<== number of member_id
    )
GROUP   BY group_id
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1                            -- <<== number of member_id
```

Will return `aa` and `dd`.

My question is: how do I filter the result if `some_id=7` ?

Comment: At first sight, the code seems to be a mess. Can you update the question with your expected output in a tabular format?

Comment: Based on your last comment you're just trying to get the `group_id` value from the `something` table for a given `some_id`. You don't need a join for that. What are you exactly doing on that query?

Comment: Given your expected output whats wrong with "select group_id from something where some_id = ?".

Comment: I changed the question, can you update?

Comment: all of you guys, you can check my answer for my own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  `group_id`
FROM    `stuff` a
WHERE   `member_id` IN (11) -- <<== list of member_id (can be 11,22 or 22,33 or 11,22,33)
AND
EXISTS
(
    SELECT  `group_id`
    FROM    `stuff` b
    WHERE a.`group_id` = b.`group_id`
    AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  c.`group_id`
        FROM      `something` c
        WHERE   c.`group_id` = b.`group_id`
        AND     c.`some_id`=7                        -- <<== number of some_id=7
    )  
    GROUP BY `group_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1               -- <<== number of member_id
)
GROUP   BY `group_id`
HAVING  COUNT(*) =1               -- <<== number of member_id
```

This will return `aa` ...what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather confusing.  Seems like a simple `JOIN` should work:

```
SELECT s.group_id
FROM stuff s 
    INNER JOIN something so ON s.group_id = so.group_id 
WHERE s.member_id = 11 AND
    so.some_id = 7
```

Comment: I changed the question, your answer is not good, can you update?

Answer (score 2):

That looks strange to me...

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * //or whatever
FROM stuff 
JOIN something ON stuff.group_id=something.group_id 
WHERE something.some_id=7 AND stuff.member_id IN (11);
```

this will return:

```
member_id    |    group_id    |    some_id    |
-----------------------------------------------
    11              aa                7
```

Comment: I changed the question, your answer is not good, can you update?

Comment: I corrected it.  Basically all you do is change the WHERE criteria.

Comment: No, WHERE   member_id IN (11) could be WHERE   member_id IN (11, 22) and HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2 so the query will return bb (I also updated the table something...check above)

Comment: everything you just said is negated by the fact that you want to filter for "some_id=7" you want a result where member_id is 11 AND some_id=7.  AND means that both conditions have to be true.

Comment: The real problem is your query is overly complicated.  Why don't you tell us what results you expect and we can give you a query for it.

Comment: There, I corrected the member_id to search on IN rather than =.  You'll still get the same result.